# listview runs successfully, but nothing is display in emulator

Tags: android, android-listview, arrays

I tried to run a simple listview application using arrays.there is no error on my program, but nothing is display in the emulator.empty screen is display.why?

This is my program:

```
package com.example.lvdb;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

      String [] values={"TAXI","FOOD","TICKET BOOKING","HOSPITAL"};

    protected void oncreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView lists=getListView();
        lists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
        lists.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

}
```

Comment: Check your xml and i think the ArrayAdapter is not adapting the strings to the list

Comment: As you are using ListActivity you do not need to define a layout for this Activity if you do not have to display anything else than ListView. You also need not define a Listview, just pass the String array to the ArrayAdapter and setListAdapter.

Answer (score 3):

1. Java is case sensitive: `protected void oncreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {..`
2. Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
3. `ListView lists=getListView();` and `lists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);` is actually the same thing (but you better use the first one)

   ```
   package com.example.lvdb;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.app.ListActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.ListAdapter;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

   public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

       String [] values={"TAXI","FOOD","TICKET BOOKING","HOSPITAL"};

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values))
       }

   }
   ```

[image]

Your case:

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {

    String [] values={"TAXI","FOOD","TICKET BOOKING","HOSPITAL"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView lists=getListView();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
        lists.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check in your xml file ID of list. It must be @+id/list

After that, get a list and set adapter.

Code :

```
        ListView lists=getListView();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Values must be set before a set adapter.